# Implicit converstion for both GenTraversableOnce and Option in one shot

Tags: scala, playframework-2.0, implicit-conversion

I'm working on a class for containing HTML body content, `<head>` content, and end-of-body content. I want to make it easy to prepend and append the latter two forms to a document as it gets generated, generalized by `trait Resource`.

Right now, with code similar to that at the bottom of this question, I can do `multipartHtml :+ resource`, `multipartHtml ++ optionResource`, `multipartHtml ++ resources`, `resource +: multipartHtml` (for types you can probably infer. I've added the following to the MultipartHtml companion object be able to do `resources ++ multipartHtml`:

```
implicit class RichResources(resources: GenTraversableOnce[Resource]) {
  def ++(that: MultipartHtml): MultipartHtml = resources.foldRight(that)(_ +: _)
}
```

But that won't let me do `optionResource ++ multipartHtml`, because `Option` is not a `GenTraversableOnce`.

Besides duplicating that for `Option`, is there a better way to capture the `Option` and `GenTraversableOnce` conversions in one shot? I tried `implicit class RichResources[T <% GenTraversableOnce](resources: T[Resource])`, and `implicit class RichResources[T[_] <% GenTraversableOnce[_](resources: T[Resource])`, with no luck. I'm also open to other ways of accomplishing this result besides the `implicit class`, if there are other methods.

Below is more code for context:

```
import play.api.templates.Html

case class MultipartHtml(bodyMarkup: Html, headTags: Seq[String], footerTags: Seq[String]) {
  import MultipartHtml._

  def ++(resources: GenTraversableOnce[Resource]): MultipartHtml = resources.foldLeft(this)(_ :+ _)

  def :+(resource: Resource): MultipartHtml = resource match {
    case s: HeadTag => MultipartHtml(bodyMarkup, (headTags :+ s.toString).distinct, footerTags)
    case s: ScriptTag => MultipartHtml(bodyMarkup, headTags, (footerTags :+ s.toString).distinct)
    case _ => this
  }

  def +:(resource: Resource): MultipartHtml = resource match {
    case s: HeadTag => MultipartHtml(bodyMarkup, (s.toString +: headTags).distinct, footerTags)
    case s: ScriptTag => MultipartHtml(bodyMarkup, headTags, (s.toString +: footerTags).distinct)
    case _ => this
  }

}

object MultipartHtml {
  /** A resource that can be imported in the HTML head or footer*/
  trait Resource

  // ... case classes implementing Resource
}
```

Comment: Can't you do something like: `optionResource.map(multipartHtml :+ _)`. Since your resource is an `Option`, I think you want the result to also be an `Option`. Or not?

Comment: @Kigyo Well, not exactly, because that would give me a `None` if `optionResource` is None, but I'd really like to leave `multipartHtml` unchanged in that case. The only purpose of `Resource` is to modify `MultipartHtml`

Comment: Then you can do: `optionResource.map(multipartHtml :+ _).getOrElse(multipartHtml)`. `Option` and `GenTraversableOnce` have only `Any` as a common superclass. So you either define it seperatly, or just use what I wrote. Is it so problematic to have another implicit?